# keep music playing changing page in NextJS while using custom _app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to get a player that keeps playing while changing pages, therefore I used the _app.tsx but it still stop while changing page.

any way I can make this work ?

my _app.tsx

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Provider store={rootStore}>
        <Child>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
          <Player />
        </Child>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone having the same problem it appears it does work if the route you are going to is not 404 (because the route does not exsist)